# Code build in Mac 10.4.4 is not working in 10.3.9?

Tags: objective-c

I have build cocoa application in  10.4.4 using (mac10.3.9sdk xcode version:2.2.1,universal binary), but when im trying to invoke the application in 10.3.9 the application is not getting invoked.

Can you please tell me what would be the probable mistakes or reasons of its not getting invoked???or How can i trouble shoot the issue?

which version of xcode should i use in 10.3.9 so that i can debug the code, can someone please provide the corresponding link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime failure could be for any number of reasons: missing libraries or frameworks, compiled with the wrong settings etc.

Probably your first port of call should be console.app if you are trying to run this on another machine that does not have the development tools installed.  It will probably give you some clues as to why the application isn't starting up.

Comment: Hey.....Thank you dude......Thanks a lot.....
When i checked in the console path i found that the application is trying to load 10.4sdk's library, so it was crashing.

I was editing the project settings but i did not observe the Target Info settings of the project.